Computing a probability in a Markov chain
I have encountered a Markov chain problem that I have been spending hours trying to understand. Consider a time-continuous homogeneous Markov chain with intensity matrix - call it $\lambda$:
\begin{bmatrix}
    -3 & 2 & 1 \\
    1 & -4 & 3 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
The question is:
Given that the process is in state $1$, what is the probability that it stays in state 1 for at least $1,5$ time units and then jumps to state $3$?
I know from my lecture notes that the interpretation of the number
$q_{ij}=\frac{\lambda_{ij}}{-\lambda_{ii}}$ is that it gives the probability of jumping from state $i$ to state $j$ given that there is a jump out of state $i$. I also know that the waiting time for a jump in state $i$ is $Expo(-\lambda_{ii})$.
If $Y_n$ denote the state after the $n$'th jump and $W_n$ denote the waiting time for the $n$'th jump, I believe that the probability can be expressed this way:
$ p=\mathbb{P}( Y_n =3, W_n>1,5|Y_{n-1} =1) $
I guess that the probability is just $\frac{1}{3}$. Since the process is Markov, I believe that the waiting time doesn't matter. If this is the case, then the probability just reduces to:
$ p=\mathbb{P}( Y_n =3|Y_{n-1} =1) =q_{13}=\frac{\lambda_{13}}{-\lambda_{11}}=\frac{1}{3} $
On the other hand, it seems unreasonable that the waiting time does not matter at all since I would expect the probability to be very small if the waiting time $1.5$ was $1000000$ instead. But I also noticed that:
$ p=\mathbb{P}( Y_n =3, W_n>1,5|Y_{n-1} =1)=\mathbb{P}( Y_n =3| W_n>1,5,Y_{n-1} =1)\mathbb{P}(W_n>1,5|Y_{n-1} =1) $
So if it is true that:
$ \mathbb{P}( Y_n =3| W_n>1,5,Y_{n-1} =1)=\mathbb{P}( Y_n =3|Y_{n-1} =1) $
Then I guess the answer must be $\frac{1}{3}*exp(-3*1,5)\approx0.0037$.

The waiting time must certainly matter for the probability of an event that references the waiting time! The waiting time merely does not matter in the sense that it is independent from the next state jumped to.

Can you give me some more details on that?

You want two things to happen: it does not jump in the first $1.5$ time units, and then (remembering the memorylessness) when it jumps it goes directly to $3$.  As you say, the probability it does not jump is $e^{-3\times 1.5}=e^{-4.5}$, and then the probability it goes directly to $3$ rather than to $2$ is $\frac{1}{2+1}$.  So your answer is correct.
